# Movie-style shotgun blast (sticky collision) with Box2D

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, box2d

I'm making a Flash game where the player throws balls of mud at objects in the sky. I'm using Box2D to model the physics. I don't want the ball to bounce off of objects (apply a normal force); instead I want it to impart its momentum on the object it is striking (like a movie-style shotgun blast).

I've tried tweaking friction and restitution, but nothing has given the effect I want. It looks like I'm going to have to work at a more gritty level, but I wanted to see if someone has a solution before I possibly reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What exactly do you want the mud ball to do upon impact with the objects in the sky?

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to make the objects in the sky take the momentum of the mud and have the mud lose little momentum, just give the mud a large density or give the objects in the sky a lower density. Use the b2BodyDef.density property. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Create a weld joint to join the objects after the collision. You'll need to create a contactlistener to accomplish this.